# How can I generate output from a PHP script in a tabular format

Tags: php, mysql, tabular

Here is an example with columns and values:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| rate | conn/s | req/s | replies/s avg | errors | net io (KB/s) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  100 | 99.9   | 99.9  | 99.7          | 0      | 45.4          |
|  120 | 119.7  | 119.7 | 120.0         | 0      | 54.4          |
|  140 | 139.3  | 139.3 | 138.0         | 0      | 63.6          |
|> 160 | 151.9  | 151.9 | 147.0         | 0      | 69.3          |
|  180 | 132.2  | 129.8 | 137.4         | 27     | 59.6          |
|  200 | 119.8  | 117.6 | 139.9         | 31     | 53.9          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: To be viewed where? In a monospaced font environment (i.e. a command line) or written to a file? A browser?

Comment: There is also a `homework` tag, and there is no shame to use it...

Comment: This is to be written to a file and the data needs to be purged on each run, so that this "result" formatted output in a file is only persisted once every execution cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [`printf`/`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
printf('| %3s | %-5.1f | …', $rate, $conns, …);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to display it in a browser and fetching data from MySQL. Use this code, replace your `dbname` and `tablename` with correct values:

```
<html>
<head><title>Result as Table</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'dbname';
$table = 'tablename';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

printf() is your friend here.

```
<?php
function printRows($rows){
    $br = "+----------------------------------------------------------------+";
    $he = "| rate | conn/s | req/s | replies/s avg | errors | net io (KB/s) |";

    //Print out the header
    print "$br\n$he\n$br\n";

    //Iterate through the rows
    foreach($rows as $row){
        printf("|[%-5s] | [%-7s] | [%-5s] | [%-13s] | [%-6s] | [%-13s] |",
               $row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5] 
              );

    }

    //Print the end ascii-art
    print "$br\n";
}
?>
```